# Let $p : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a non-constant polynomial, that is, for all...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, problem-solving

> Let $p : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a non-constant polynomial, that is, for all $x \in \mathbb R$;$p(x) =a_0 + a_1x +... + a_nx^ n$, with $a_n \neq 0$ and $n \ge 1$. Prove that if $n$ is even then $lim_{x \to + \infty} p(x) =lim_{x \to - \infty} p(x) = + \infty$ if $a_n \gt 0 $ and = $- \infty$ if $an \lt 0$.

what was i able to do

We write

$P(x) = a_n x^n( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{a_k}{a_nx^{n-k}}+1)$.If $n$ is even $lim_{x \to \infty} x^na_n = \infty =lim_{x \to -\infty} x^na_n $ with $a_n \gt 0$ and $lim_{x \to \infty}x^n a_n = - \infty = lim_{x\to - \infty } x^n a_n$ if $a_n \lt 0$, so the same goes for $P(x)$ If $n$ is odd $lim_{x \to \infty} x^na_n = \infty$ and $lim_{x \to -\infty}x^n a_n = -\infty$ with $a_n \gt 0$, case $a_n \lt 0$ we have $lim_{x \to \infty}x^na_n = -\infty$ and $lim_{x \to - \infty} x^n a_n = \infty$.

How it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title is really vague! To attract the right kind of attention from people interested in/able to answer your question, please use a better, relevant title

Comment: I think that the “so the same goes for $P(x)$” part requires some justification. Besides, the question is only about what happens when $n$ is even.

Comment: Also, I say this so often, when in MathJax doubt, backslashes are your friend: `\lim` is the thing you are after

Comment: As Jose says, to conclude properly you should show that the sum in brackets tends to $1$ as $|x|\to\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Your question and proof is quite clumsy. So, here's my attempt at a neat argument-

Since even polynomials are even functions, it suffices to check only for $x\to \infty$.

Now, as $x^n$ grows faster than $x^k$ for any $k<n$,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} p(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty} a_nx^n$$
and hence
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} p(x)=\begin{cases}
+\infty &\text{ if $a_n>0$}\\
-\infty &\text{ if $a_n<0$}
\end{cases}$$

If you feel that the "$x_n$ grows faster than $x^k$" part is not rigorous enough, try making it so- if you're unsuccessful, I will place an edit.